# Função jQuery Menu select url browser

Tags: jquery

Como faço para o codigo `window.location.href` da certo com o `value` do `<option`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $('select').find('option[value=window.location.href]').attr('selected','selected');
        });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```

Exemplo url browser:http://www.test.com/page8 ser o selecionado

```
<select>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8" selected="selected" >United States dollar (USD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é disso que vc precisa:

```js
$(function(){
 $('select').find('option').each(function(key){
  if($(this).val() == 'http://www.test.com/page8'){
          $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
   <option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```

Também pode ser assim:

```js
$(function(){
var url = "http://www.test.com/page8";
  $('select').find('option[value="' + url +'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');  
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
   <option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```